# JPA: What happens when changing JoinColumn to mappedBy?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I currently have a relation where a parent entity knows about its children like so:

```
@Entity
public class Parent{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
public class Child{
    // no link to parent
}
```

Now I want to make it a bidirectional relationship like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
public class Child{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

The underlying database is an OracleDB.

What will happen to my existing data when doing above change? We don't want to mess up the existing data if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What happens? 
They are for different concepts.

*"mappedBy"* is used to interrelate both ends of a bidirectional relation.

`@JoinColumn` specified as you have for a 1-N simply says "store the relation in a FK in the other side". This doesn't mean that the relation is bi- or uni- directional, could be either.

Using the `@JoinColumn` is advisable, so you make it clear that it is via a FK in the related object.

Comment: So by removing the @JoinColumn will my FK (I guess it's implicitly stored in Child) be removed or reused in the mappedBy-FK?

Comment: Nothing is "removed" unless you remove it. Leaving the `@JoinColumn` tells it to use the FK (that you already have).

Answer (score 0):

To create bidirectional @OneToMany it is correct to use mappedBy. It sets the owner of relationship. In database foreign key is set on child entity.

Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.
In your `Parent` class, create `addChild` and `removeChild` methods like these:

```
public void addChild(Child child) {
        children.add( child );
        child.setParent( this );
    }

    public void removeChild(Child child) {
        children.remove( child);
        child.setParent( null );
    }
```

Comment: Yes I know the difference. I was wondering what would happen to existing data when switching between JoinColumn and mappedBy

Answer (score 0):

I managed to keep the existing relationships from parents to children.

For that I looked up the name of the column for the foreign key directly in the database, in this case `CHILD_ID` in the table `CHILD`. This column contains the ID of the Parent (auto-generated).

Now I simply hardcoded this name into the JPA. It's a weird naming now, but no data was lost.

Here the final code:

```
@Entity
public class Parent{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
public class Child{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID") // <- for data migration
    private Parent parent;
}
```